# What causes people who come in contact with the "Time Fruit" to change?

Tags: mnemosyne

What causes only males to turn into blood-wing angels and only females into immortals?

There have been occurrences of both happening to some people. Was that ever explained?

[image: Time Fruit]

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemosyne_(anime)#Antagonists), Apos posses qualities of both an angel and an immortal because he is a hermaphrodite, or more properly an intersex person according to Wikipedia. however i haven't seen the series so i can't verify it myself

Comment: @Memor-X i can verify that , at the end of episode 6 when Apos become angel , development of lust in both Mimi and Rin is seen, which did not happen before when Apos met Rin and when Rin became the new Guardian and release the wing , it seems like Apos is suffering from the same lust as other immortal women does when they are near angel